# trim a string a number of characters after a delimiter

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have the below string:

```
57,5804748535
```

I would like to trim it so it looks like this:

```
57,58
```

I've tried to use `cut` and `awk` but to no avail, also I can't find anything on google, is there a way, perhaps using `sed` (or maybe bc)?

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything left to the comma and two characters after comma:

```
echo $x |grep -oP '^.*,.{2}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to keep all the characters left to the colon and only two after the colon. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @Cvg use `grep -oP '^.*,.{2}'`